# How to track failed logon attempts using Unified Auditing

Tags: oracle, windows, oracle-12c, audit

I activated a `ORA_LOGON_FAILURES` policy and I've tried to execute

> select * from unified_audit_trail where unified_audit_policies = 'ORA_LOGON_FAILURES';

But it doesn't work. All my failed attempts to log in weren't audited. So what do I do wrong?

Comment: which oracle version you are using?

Comment: @Md Haidar Ali Khan 12.1.0.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have enabled `ORA_LOGON_FAILURES`, but have you enabled Unified Auditing properly?

With the default, mixed-mode auditing, setting `audit_trail` to `none`, prevents logon failures to be audited with `ORA_LOGON_FAILURES` enabled.

This is how it works with everything set to default (audit_trail set to `DB` by DBCA):

```
SQL> audit policy ora_logon_failures;

Audit succeeded.

SQL> select count(*) from unified_audit_trail 
     where unified_audit_policies = 'ORA_LOGON_FAILURES' and return_code = 1017;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> connect 1/1
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL> connect / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from unified_audit_trail
     where unified_audit_policies = 'ORA_LOGON_FAILURES' and return_code = 1017;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

Also, Unified Audit entires can be buffered in the SGA and be written to disk later and not immediately, in that case, flush manually before querying:

```
EXEC DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.flush_unified_audit_trail;
```

Still, if you configured everything properly, you may have hit:

**BUG 19383839 - UNIFIED AUDIT - NO LOGON OR FAILED LOGON ACTION CAPTURED**

*Edit:*

Ok, so I had to test it myself, else I would not have believed it. Opposing to what the documentation states ([AUDIT_TRAIL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-BD86F593-B606-4367-9FB6-8DAB2E47E7FA.htm#REFRN10006)), setting the `audit_trail` to `none` does have an effect even when using pure Unified Auditing. But this is not intended, it is a bug. The fix is not included in the latest PSU (12.1.0.2.170117), but installing the above one-off patch (19383839) indeed resolved the issue. The problem is, this patch is not available to Windows platform. (I have tested this both on Linux and Windows, because Windows is always a factor you need to consider when working with Oracle.)

Setting `audit_trail` to `DB` does not reenable mixed-mode, relinking (renaming the DLL) enables pure Unified Auditing and that overrides this, you can confirm this by selecting from `AUD$` or `DBA_AUDIT_SESSION`. So I suggest that you set `audit_trail` to `DB`.

Comment: You have enabled ORA_LOGON_FAILURES . +1

Comment: If I got you right, I have to enable mix-mode auditing with AUDIT_TRAIL='db,extended'. Right?

Comment: @Denis Lolik Not necessarily, `audit_trail=db` works as well.

Comment: @Balazs Papp I mean what if I do not activate audit_trail? Mix-mode decreases performance.

Comment: @Denis Lolik Mixed-mode is the default. You can enable pure Unified Auditing by relinking the binaries with the Unified Auditing option. In a pure Unified Auditing environment, `audit_trail` has no effect. Still, you have not told us what you did besides activating the `ORA_LOGON_FAILURES` policy, so I do not know what environment you use.

Comment: @Balazs Papp I only have set the AUDIT_TRAIL to NONE and renamed the file %ORACLE_HOME%/bin/orauniaud12.dll.option to %ORACLE_HOME%/bin/orauniaud12.dll. That's all.

Comment: @Denis Lolik Ok, so I updated my answer. Long story short: it is a bug, and requires a one-off patch to be installed. Unfortunately for you, this patch is not available to Windows. However you can still set `audit_trail` to `DB`, with the Unified Auditing option enabled (`SELECT VALUE FROM V$OPTION WHERE PARAMETER = 'Unified Auditing';`), the database overrides that setting.

Comment: @Balazs Papp Thank you! I did what you have suggested and it's working now. But, for example, 'dba_audit_session' is still empty as well as the other views which are relevant to audit.

Comment: @Denis Lolik That is the point. `DBA_AUDIT_SESSION` and old views return data from the old audit (`AUD$`), and they are supposed to return no data with pure Unified Auditing. You should select data from the view `UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL`.

Comment: @Balazs Papp Well. Thank you so much one more time.